# kendo-grid-messages apply for all column

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have a problem when using

```
      <kendo-grid-column field="isActive" [title]="l('Status')" filter="boolean">
          <kendo-grid-messages filterIsTrue="Yes" filterIsFalse="NO">
          </kendo-grid-messages>
            ......... 
        </kendo-grid-column>
```

[kendo version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9ipt.png)

all kendo-grid-column with filter="boolean" will have same kendo-grid-messages and that no acceptable

I'm trying to make kendo-grid-messages just apply in a one column or use a different approach that makes me do the same behavior of kendo-grid-message where should apply in one column in angular

Answer (score 0):

The `kendo-grid-messages` component is applied for each grid instance it appears in. This means that its scope is the whole grid. Even if you place multiple instances of `kendo-grid-messages` inside several `kendo-grid-column` components, only one of the message overrides will be used in the entire grid.

One option is to use a custom 2 option dropdown filter instead of each of the  boolean filters you have in the grid.